# Is it possible to standardise data in SQL Queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query which is similar to an answer to a previous question:

```
WITH CteTally(N) AS(
    SELECT N FROM(VALUES
        (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11), (12)
    )t(N)
),
CteDates(YearPart, MonthPart, YearName, MonthName) AS(
    SELECT
        DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(MONTH, t.N - 1, DATEADD(YEAR, a.Y - 1900, 0))),
        DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, t.N - 1, DATEADD(YEAR, a.Y - 1900, 0))),
        DATENAME(YEAR, DATEADD(MONTH, t.N - 1, DATEADD(YEAR, a.Y - 1900, 0))),
        DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, t.N - 1, DATEADD(YEAR, a.Y - 1900, 0)))
    FROM(
        SELECT DISTINCT DATEPART(YEAR, call_date) AS Y
        FROM rm_report
    )a
    CROSS JOIN CteTally t
)
SELECT
    COUNT(r.call_date) AS Events,
    d.YearPart,
    d.MonthPart,
    d.YearName,
    d.MonthName
FROM CteDates d
LEFT JOIN rm_report r
    ON d.YearPart = DATEPART(YEAR, r.call_date)
    AND d.YearName= DATENAME(YEAR, r.call_date)
    AND d.MonthPart = DATEPART(MONTH, r.call_date)
    AND d.MonthName = DATENAME(MONTH, r.call_date)
WHERE surrived = 'Y'
GROUP BY
    d.YearPart, d.YearName, d.MonthPart, d.MonthName
ORDER BY
    d.YearName, d.MonthPart
```

Essentially it is intended to count the number of survival events per month / year.  I would like to be able to standardised this data.  That is, divide the number of survival events each month by the total number of events.  This way the data has more meaning as the total number of events varies per month.

Is there a way that I can do this from within the query?  This particular query is running against MS SQL.

After the suggestions below, I modified the SQL as follows:

remove the WHERE clause and replace

```
COUNT(r.call_date) AS Events,
```

With

```
COALESCE (SUM(CASE WHEN r.survived='Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1.0 / NULLIF(COUNT(r.call_date),0),)* 100 AS Events
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try

```
...
SELECT 
  SUM(CASE survived WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / 
  COUNT(r.call_date) AS NormalisedEvents,
....
```

Comment: This seems to be working, however I need to account for no events in a month - and hence a divide by zero?  I'm not sure how to test for this?

Comment: Ok - I have used COALESCE / NULLIF - I will post a full solution after I have tested

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You can calculate the yearly total separately, and then join that result into your query, or you can use a partition:

```
Select MonthPart, YearPart
,Count(r.Call_Date) over (partition by YearPart, MonthPart) *1.0
       / Count(r.call_date) over () as StandardizedEvents
```

The `*1.0` is a simple way to convert to decimal so you avoid integer division.

ETA: If you wanted to calculate survived events over the total, use this:

```
Select MonthPart, YearPart
,Count(case when survived = 'Y' then r.Call_Date end) over (partition by YearPart, MonthPart) *1.0
       / Count(r.call_date) over () as StandardizedEvents
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/841b1/2/0

Comment: I think the question is about dividing events where `surrived = 'Y'` by the total number of events. And I suspect it might even be `survived`...

Comment: @mustaccio thanks!  I have edited my answer to add that (also assuming your alternate spelling is probably right).

Comment: Yes, I am looking for the survival rate per month.  I will try the second solution...

Comment: @APH I am getting a "survived" is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either and aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause error.  I have had these errors before, but don't really understand how to resolve?

Comment: You don't need the `group by` if you are using partitions, @skyman.  You may want to add "distinct" though.

Comment: Thank you - this is helpful